# MsgBox based on 2 values in different cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I am completely a VBA novice and am trying to achieve the following, without success.I would really appreciate your help.

What I need to achieve:
If someone selects for each row Action = "Delete" AND Summary = "True"
then MsgBox "Alert:   If the Block is deleted, the child networks and hosts will also be deleted

[image]
This should be able to work for all the rows A, B 1-202

I know what I need to do , but I don't know the syntax.    Here is what I have already put together.  It only works if I select A2 = "Delete".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A138")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("A2")
            Case "Delete": MsgBox "Alert:   If the Block is deleted, the child networks and hosts will also be deleted"
           
        End Select
    End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, good job!

> It only works if I select A2 = "Delete".

That's because of this: `Select Case Range("A2")`. You only told it to look at `A2`. If you want it to look at the value in column A of whatever row got changed, you could use this: `Select Case Range("A" & Target.Row)`. References inside the `Range()` function are strings so they work like the `Indirect()` function in the worksheet. You can piece them together.

Also, there is no check to see if the user also selected "True" in column B. The code below is my crack at a solution that'll work for you. I happen to prefer nested `If` statements only because I've used them more then `Select Case` but you're welcome to rework this into the format you're most comfortable with.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:B138")) Is Nothing Then
        If UCase(Range("A" & Target.Row)) = "DELETE" Then
            If UCase(Range("B" & Target.Row)) = "TRUE" Then
                MsgBox "Alert:   If the Block is deleted, the child networks and hosts will also be deleted", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

There are a few things here that function differently than your code in the question.

1. I expanded the `Intersect` range to include column B so that changes in either column will trigger this subroutine.
2. I convert the range value using `UCase` and compare it to `DELETE` because the default comparison is binary, not text-based, so that `Delete` and `dElEtE` are not equal. If your user ever types "delete" instead of using the drop-down, this code will still work.
3. I added a check for the value in column B.
4. I prettied up your message box with `vbExclamation`.

[image: SCreenshot]

Comment: Nice job. I love me some `vbExclamation`/`vbQuestion`/`vbInformation`. They're rarely used.

Comment: Wow, thanks!   That works great.  Exactly what I needed.   You're awesome!